# Identify Slash with Regex

Tags: regex, vb.net

I am trying to identify any type of slash with regex.

Either forward or backslash ("/" or "\")

I have not been able to make it work.

Here is what I have so far:

```
Public Shared Function CheckSlash(mystring as string) As boolean
    CheckSlash = New boolean

    If Regex.IsMatch(mystring, "^[/]+$") = True Then
        CheckSlash = True
    Else
        CheckSlash = False
    End If
End Function
```

Comment: What problem do you get?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regex -

`[/\\]`

Depending on vb.net string escaping rules its

`"[/\\]"` or `"[/\\\\]"`

Answer (score 0):

Use this regex:

```
[\\/]
```

This will help

Comment: @ErwinBolwidt, I don't know the escaping rules of vb. I know c# So thought, to leave it to OP to figure it out, rather than giving a wrong answer

Answer (score 0):

The pattern `^[/]+$` matches any string that consists *only* of one or more forward slashes.

If you want to match any string that consists only of one or more forward or back slashes, use a pattern like this:

```
^[/\\]+$
```

If you want to know if the string simply contains a forward or back slash, drop the anchors and the quantifier, use a pattern like this:

```
[/\\]
```

And I'd recommend rewriting the function like this:

```
Public Shared Function CheckSlash(mystring as string) As Boolean
    CheckSlash = Regex.IsMatch(mystring, "[/\\]")
End Function
```

However, if you just want to ensure that the string consists of *exactly one* forward or back slashes, I wouldn't use regular expressions:

```
Public Shared Function CheckSlash(mystring as string) As Boolean
    CheckSlash = mystring = "/" OrElse mystring = "\\"
End Function
```